# Bind viewbag from jquery call in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I want to bind ViewBag data .

I have a method which return a File .

That method  called by ajax call because i want to put condition based on response .

```
public JsonResult GetPDF()
        {
                    string Path = GenerateQuotePdf();
                    bool IsDocumentInserted = objQuoteDocumentDAL.InsertQuoteDocuments(SessionInfo.QuoteID, SessionInfo.VersionID, 0, Path, Utility.QuoteType, SessionInfo.AgentCode, DateTime.Now);

                    QuoteDocumentModel objQuoteDocumentModel = new QuoteDocumentModel();
                    List<QuoteDocumentModel> lstQuoteDocumentModel = objQuoteDocumentDAL.GetQuoteDocumentsByType(SessionInfo.QuoteID, SessionInfo.VersionID, Utility.QuoteType);
                    if (lstQuoteDocumentModel.Count > 0)
                    {
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/" + lstQuoteDocumentModel[0].Path), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        ViewBag.IframeUrl = File(fs, "application/pdf");
                    }
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        IsDownloaded = "true"
                    });

        }
```

Above method i call by jquery ajxa call using below function .

```
function DownloadPDFFile() {
    $.ajax({
        url: GetPDFURL,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (ex) {
            $(ProcessingModal).modal('hide');
            $(txtloginuservalid).css('display', 'block');
            $(txtloginPasswordvalid).css('display', 'block');

        }
    });
}
```

I want to bind view bag into iframe .

```
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="ifrmQuote" width = "80%"  height="800" src="@ViewBag.IframeUrl"></iframe>
```

But when page loaded successfully , i look into inspact element then source='' bind .

Please suggest some idea for it .

I hope you can understand my problem .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to use *View*Bag, but not using a *View* ?

Comment: Using view . but i call method using ajax call. so it return a null value.

Comment: Using an *action* yes, not a *view*: `return Json(...` your Json won't have anything to do with the ViewBag because it's not a view.   To clarify, the ViewBag is *only* available in a `.cshtml` view/partial view; you do not use a .cshtml file to render/generate the output.

Comment: I think you should do it by jquery or javascript like : you should get alll the required data in the ajax success function and then assign that value to i frame by id

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix how ?

Comment: You should be able to return the url in the JSON:  `return Json(new { url: iframe.url, isDownloaded=true });` - but look closer, your "url" is a `File` object, not a url at all.

Comment: according to me you have called one method by ajax and then you set all the required data in view bag and then assign that view bag to i frame but that is not working .So I want that you should not set any value to view bag just get that details in ajax success function by returning that from the called method in json format or by using return json and then you can assign the the value to the iframe by javascript by using its id .

Comment: @Anurag_Systematix  , then tell me how to assign FileStream to iframe using jquery ?

Comment: You can't assign a filestream to an iframe at all.  The `src=` attribute is an href / url.  Which you are not generating because you're attempting to return a file object via ajax.

Comment: @freedomn-m ,   $('#ifrmQuote').attr('src', GetPDFURL); where GetPDFURL is action path and that action return filestream then my iframe is fill up in right way . but i want to call ajax call and i want to assign that response to iframe ,that i am not able to do .

Comment: Yes, it works when you you point your iframe `src=` to a url / *action*.  You don't point `src=` to a filestream directly but to something that returns a filestream.  So your ajax method needs to return an appropriate url to an action that can be assigned to the iframe's `src=`.   The iframe takes that `src=` (url), calls the action and displays the content - you can't assign the content directly via `src=`.

Comment: This is one of the problems of using `dynamic` (ie the `ViewBag`) - you have a property named `url` but it's *not* a url, it's a filestream.  Try this instead: `string iframeUrl = File(fs, "application/pdf"); ViewBag.IFrameUrl = iframeUrl;` - you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: The solution is that you don't need the ajax call - change `GetPDF` to return the `File` directly and set the `src=` on the iframe to `<iframe src='@Url.Action("GetPDF")'></iframe>`

Comment: @freedomn-m , but i want to put progress bar  . if i call using ajax then i can wait util response and i can put progress bar .in your trick , it is not possible .give me idea accordingly your trick for put progress bar .

Comment: There's nothing about progress bar in the question - even if you could set the iframe directly to content, it woudn't give a progress bar.

Comment: but it take 1-2 min load iframe .so i need progress bar .

Comment: i mention   ""want to put condition based on response ."" in my question .